# mysql Dependent not null columns

Tags: mysql

I have 30 columns in tables out of which four are dependent

1. Debit Amount in Entered Currency
2. Credit Amount in Entered Currency
3. Debit Amount in Functional Currency
4. Credit Amount in Functional Currency

Below are the logic that I am looking for (its already implemented in PHP program, so 99.99% secured but I want to have it both program as well as in DB level)

a.  If column 1 is not null then column 3 should be not null and column 2/4 should be null

b.  If column 2 is not null then column 4 should be not null and column 1/3 should be null

Same for 3 and 4

This is the logic used by Oracle in R12 and Fusion Application

Thanks

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? A constraint that will enforce this logic inside the database?

Comment: Yes thats true..all these logics inside table as any wrong data in this table can screw the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

may be like this

```
ALTER TABLE transactions
ADD CHECK abs(dr-ifnull(cr,0))=dr or abs(dr-ifnull(cr,0))=cr
```

Comment: Not an option for MySQL sadly :-/

Comment: @user2959149 I'm pretty sure you're stuck with triggers.